# How can I use JSON_EXTRACT in MySQL and get a string without the quotes?

Tags: mysql

If I have a simple SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"username":"Alexander"}', '$.username');
```

I would expect it to return `Alexander` , but instead it returns `"Alexander"`.
How can I get rid of the quotes? Why does this function even return the quotes too?

Comment: Use [JSON_UNQUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) or [column->>path](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) (MySQL 5.7.13 and later): `The ->> operator can be used wherever JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT()) would be allowed.`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use `JSON_UNQUOTE` to achieve this.

```
select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(base, '$.scope')) as scope from t_name
```

ref: [Functions That Modify JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote)

Answer (score -6):

you can use replace() with it to remove quotation marks

```
SELECT replace(JSON_EXTRACT('{"username":"Alexander"}', '$.username'), '\"', '');
```

Comment: This is working only if there is no " in the value. This shouldn't be used. In json, " are encoded with \". JSON_EXTRACT returns directly the value without converting it to plain text. Not only you remove all " but you'll end up with extra \.
Correct me if I am wrong!