# Inset API output (JSON) into SQLite using SQLite API

Tags: android, json, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to store my data. I have an output from Firebase in JSON format-->

https://fundeasy-b6187.firebaseio.com/Test.json

```
{"iID":15,"vValue":"K"}
```

I want to select it using an SQLite command. SQLite has json_extract and json_set functionalities. Can these be used to select data directly from my JSON output?

Comment: You want to select??? What?

Comment: Hello,

My JSON output ( https://fundeasy-b6187.firebaseio.com/Test.json ) has two parameters iID and vValue. Their values will change everyday.

I want to select the current iID and vValue parameters from JSON using SQLite query.

Comment: Why dont you just use JSON itself from Java Default classes called JSONObject, JSONarray etc. Why sqlite?

Comment: I am using a third party service to develop my Android app. I don't have access to most of the code here. I can only define SQLite APIs with custom code. Hence, I was wondering if there is a way to achieve it in SQLite.

Comment: I didnt know if there is a json extension in sqlite so i go and check the documentation and I have written you an answer! Scroll to see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do according to the official `SQLite` documentation on `JSON`. The way to extract a certain value from a `JSON Object` and for your case the json object is:

```
{"iID":15,"vValue":"K"}
```

When selecting first you need to know the `keys` of your json object so as to get the values. For your case the keys are `iID` and another key is `vValue`. Remember they are case sensitive.

To get the values from your json object we use the sqlite function called `json_extract` function whose syntax is as follows for your case for :

```
json_extract('your json object here', '$.key_of_the_value')
```

Hence for your case it will be:

For iID

```
json_extract('your_json_object_here', '$.iID')
```

And for vValue

```
json_extract('your_json_object_here', '$.vValue')
```

Hence to summarize everything for your case the solution will be:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('your_json_object_here', '$.iID');
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('your_json_object_here', '$.vValue');
```

For more information for the extract function and json extension for sqlite like extracting json arrays or items in an json
array [check this link](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex). Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you so much in explaining it in depth. This is really helpful. I will try out the solution.

Comment: Give it an upvote and accept it as an answer to your question in the left side!

Comment: Hello, I have accepted it as the answer to my question. I am unable to upvote as I don't have enough reputation points. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can.
suppose you need to extract iID you can use the following code

' SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"iID":15,"vValue":"K"}', 'YOUR VARIABLE');'

See the following link for more
[customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403039/how-can-i-use-json-extract-in-mysql-and-get-a-string-without-the-quotes)

Comment: Hello Vidya,

Thanks a lot for your answer. In this case my JSON output will change everyday i.e. https://fundeasy-b6187.firebaseio.com/Test.json will have different values of iID and vValue.

How can the query be defined so it takes variable values of iID and vValue from my JSON output ( https://fundeasy-b6187.firebaseio.com/Test.json )