# How to get a particular word from the syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

My row value is this:

```py
{
    "df8fb54b-dc58-2342-a5ee-2fdg4536h76": {
        "doc_name": "Missing File",
        "details": {
            "e2341431-ed8a-6aa4-b4541-d11771ae2456": "updated, No reference"
        }
    }
}
```

From this, I want my output as `updated, No reference`

Tried `substring(syntax, position)`

I want to get only `updated, No reference` as an output from that syntax.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Need more info, row name, column name, does the value always contain the same amount of characters before "updated, no reference" ?

Comment: Add the sample string where from you wants this output.

Comment: I have 9k records under the column name - Comments, there is no specific row name. 
All the records contain the same number of characters before 'updated, no reference'. The only difference is few columns have 'Not updated, reference'. I want to pull only words like 'updated no reference' as my final output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `JSON_EXTRACT` to parse json value out of a column string:

```sql
-- Change column_name and table_name depending on your table
Select
  JSON_EXTRACT(column_name, '$.df8fb54b-dc58-2342-a5ee-2fdg4536h76.details.e2341431-ed8a-6aa4-b4541-d11771ae2456')
From table_name
```

It should result in `"updated, No reference"` quotes included. If you want to remove them also, see this question: [How can I use JSON_EXTRACT in MySQL and get a string without the quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37403039/4636715)

I assumed you are going to have the same keys for each and every case, as it is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mysql version above 5.7.17 you can use `JSON_EXTRACT`. Else you'll have to use `SUBSTRING` function.

Example of using `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(LabelName, 119, 21) FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%details%';
```

This query will fetch column containing 'details' and the `SUBSTRING` function will trim from position 119, of length 21. But, this query is bit weird. If you're column is JSON, then upgrade to higher version of mysql which support `JSON_EXTRACT` function or fetch the column as such and process it in application level code.